# How do I obtain the internal output of cmake (for use in manual Qt linking)

Tags: qt, cmake

I'm currently working on a project which includes `pcl` and `vtk`, among other libraries. These all use `cmake`, which is fine as long as my project uses cmake.

I prefer to use `qt creator`, and find using `qmake` more easy to understand. I wish to maintain lists of libraries to link in `qt creator .pri files` (see [this sample](http://jamesgregson.blogspot.com/2011/11/getting-things-done-with-qmake.html) for an example of what I want to follow/do). Or, in minimal-example fashion, I want to create a list of -lpcl_whatever that I would need to compile a `pcl` application.

With `cmake`, this list of libraries is generated internally using find_packages et. al., is there any way I can output the list of libraries generated to a text file or stdout such that I can build lists of libraries which need to be linked for a given library (pcl, vtk, etc.)?

Current 'part' answer:-
cmake --find-package gives me the list of include directories, but no analogue seems to exist for --find-library

Currently I'm building an example project with vtk/pcl using cmake and then copy-pasting some of the content from CMakeFiles/.dir/build.make. It seems to work, but until I progress further into my project I have no way of knowing whether this list is sufficient or exhaustive.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I found the [`--graphviz` option](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake.1.html) useful for this purpose. It creates a `.dot` file with a complete graph of all the library dependencies in the project.

Comment: You are doing strange things. Please read http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html.

Comment: Either use cmake or qmake.  Trying to use cmake to help write a qmake file will likely just create a mess.

Comment: Man, I forgot to look back at this question. How do I get notified when a comment has been added, I wonder. Nevermind, I'll figure that out.

Regarding the question itself, as I said, I prefer qmake, but other libraries which I'm using use cmake. I don't want to use cmake in my own project, hence I'm left trying to list down ALL libraries in pcl (this takes 150+ lines currently from what I can tell from my manually generated list of libs). Since pcl/vtk are both using cmake, surely there's a way to obtain the list of libraries which would be used in cmake?